# Visual Studio for Mac, open a .sln created with Windows

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-mac

I am using OS X and Visual Studio for Mac and would like to open a visual studio project ".sln" created on windows.

Unfortunately I get this error : "**Unknown solution item type**", 
[image: here an example]

How can I bypass this issue?

Comment: please repair your .csproj files Then save. Reload again.

Answer (score 0):

Visual Studio for Mac from its first preview requires .NET Core projects to be upgraded to .NET Core latest SDK, which is MSBuild based and no longer uses .xproj and project.json.

You have to manually upgrade the solution via `dotnet migrate` command, and then the generated files can be opened in VS for Mac.